# why navigation in alert is not working in react-native

Tags: react-native, alert

This is my code in which I tried navigation in alert and if I write `Alert.alert` in my code, alert won't be shown. Why?

```js
if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
    alert('Card Add Successfully ',
        [
        {
            text: 'OK',
            onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Home')
        },
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
    );

} else alert('Failed!');
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for Alert? https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert

Answer (score 1):

use like this:

```
import {  Alert } from 'react-native';
...

 Alert.alert('Title','Card Add Successfully ',
              [
                {
                  text: 'OK',
                  onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Home')
                },
              ],
              { cancelable: false }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

because alert is a window method and doesn't implement the prop onPress, so you need to import react native Alert in order to pass your desired function to onPress.

Comment: Thank you! I got it